# Python - sort a list of tuples in decreasing order with respect to a tuple element and in increasing order with respect to another element

Tags: python, list, lambda, tuples

I have a list of tuples where sorting has to be done based on 2 fields of a tuple.

Input is of the form :

```
single_custom_sort_test([inputList], [outputList])
```

inputList:

```
[name, age, height]
```

Age must be in decreasing order and height must be in increasing order.

Output must be as follows:
[image]

Sorting has to be done based on the 1st and 2nd element of the tuple (i.e numbers)

How to solve it using lambda?

Comment: Please include the code you've attempted this problem with, and the expected output, as formatted text in the body of your question.

Comment: Please post code as text so that one can easily copy&paste.

Comment: But here you pass output as a parameter? This looks like Prolog...

Comment: the pure sorting lambda should be something like :  `sortedData = sorted(data, key = lambda x: -x[1]*1000+x[2])` .. you can easily figure out why if you compute every sortingvalue for  every person-tuple you provide - just remember the computed value is just used for sorting, no values are changed at any point.